# Telegram - how to get user arcive stories/posts with telethon?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

On desktop client "User info" window there is "posts" button and it opens "[Posted stories](https://telegram.org/tour/stories#stories-on-your-profile)" with photos and videos. Some are grouped to story somehow(no grouping in web version though). So, how to get it and download it?

For profile photos I can do:

```
photos_list = await client.get_profile_photos(user)
for photo in photos_list:
    await client.download_media(photo)
```

But what with this posts? There is this function.

```
res = await client(
                functions.stories.ReadStoriesRequest(
                    user_id=user.id, 
                    max_id=user.stories_max_id
                )
            )
```

But users I'm parsing have:

```
stories_hidden = False
stories_max_id = None
stories_unavailable = True
```

And yet some of them have like 100+ "posts", so obviously I'm doing something wrong.